# Redirect method call at runtime to introduce some kind of sandbox

Tags: java, java-7

*I'm in bit of a fix with this problem. Hoping for a silver bullet.*

I have a few singletons(~10) which all have a few functions (~10 each). My function calls look like this (as they should). *Note: Most of these calls are async and do not return anything. Only a handful are synchronous*

```
SingletonClassGorrilla.getInstance().methodSwim(swimmingPool, lifeJacket, whistle);
SingletonClassRacoon.getInstance().methodBark(thief, owner);
```

I need to put all these calls in a sandbox:

```
Sandbox.runThisInSandboxMode(new Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run(){
        SingletonClassGorrilla.getInstance().methodSwim(swimmingPool, lifeJacket, whistle);
    }
});
```

As the number of places where they are being called is huge, I am hoping that the `sandboxMode` can be achieved at the Singleton end.

Possible solution (but infeasible because of the number of functions I will have to wrap like this):

```
public class SingletonClassGorrilla{
    public void methodSwim(WaterBody waterBody, Instrument instrument, 
            EmResponse emResponse){

        Sandbox.runThisInSandboxMode(new Runnable{
            @Override
            public void run(){
                methodSwim(swimmingPool, lifeJacket, whistle, true);
            }
        });

    }

    private void methodSwim(WaterBody waterBody, Instrument instrument, 
            EmResponse emResponse, boolean fromSandbox){

        // Do your thang.

    }
}
```

**Is there anyway, through use of reflection / annotations / any other thing in the language, which can reduce the amount of changes required?**

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) with a suitable `InvocationHandler` (though you'd have to pull out an `interface` for each of your singletons).  Disclaimer:  I haven't tried to actually compile/run this code, but it should give you the general idea.  If you care about return values from your singleton, you may have to use `Callable` instead of/in addition to `Runnable` in your sandbox interface.

```
public class SingletonGorilla implements GorillaInterface {
  private static SingletonGorilla theRealGorilla;
  public static GorillaInterface getInstance() {
    //In reality, you'd want to store off the Proxy as well
    return Proxy.newProxyInstance(SingletonGorilla.class.getClassLoader(), GorillaInterface.class, new SandboxingHandler());
  }

  private static class SandboxingHandler implements InvocationHandler () {
  public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) {
    return Sandbox.runInSandbox( new Runnable() {
      public void run () {
        method.invoke(proxy, args));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd remove the lambda, the question is tagged as java-7.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking about something along the following lines:
First, you'll need an interface for each of your singletons:

Interface:

```
package org.test.proxywrapper;

public interface IGorilla {

    public void methodSwim();

}
```

Implementing class:

```
package org.test.proxywrapper;

public class Gorilla implements IGorilla{

    public void methodSwim()
    {

    }
}
```

Then, implement an InvocationHandler that factorize the code that will be common to each call to the methods of Gorilla:

```
package org.test.proxywrapper;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class WrapperInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object arg0, Method arg1, Object[] arg2) throws Throwable {

        Sandbox.runThisInSandboxMode(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Object params = new Object[0];
                try {
                    arg1.invoke(arg0, new Object[]{});
                } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        // return something if you need to
        return new Object();
    }
}
```

At this point, in a central place in your application/system, wrap each singleton with a Proxy, and pass the proxy reference around instead of the original wrapped object:

```
package org.test.proxywrapper;

import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String argv[])
    {
        WrapperInvocationHandler wrapperInvocationHandler =  new WrapperInvocationHandler();
        Class<?>[] implementedTypes = new Class<?>[1];
        implementedTypes[0] = IGorilla.class;
        IGorilla proxy = (IGorilla) Proxy.newProxyInstance(Main.class.getClassLoader(), implementedTypes, wrapperInvocationHandler);
        proxy.methodSwim();
    }
}
```

This simple example compiles and runs as I would expect.
I cut some corners here, skipped the getInstance method, etc, but I guess it gives an idea of how it can be done.

Comment: what would the handler do when there are multiple methods in the singleton. How would it know which to call. would the invoke call handle the routing? How?

Comment: The second parameter of `invoke` (`Method arg1`) is a reference to the reflected method that's being called, you can write `arg1.invoke(arg0, new Object[]{})`, see the edited answer in a minute.